# Reproductor de video

Tags: html, css, video

Quisiera ver si me pueden ayudar con un par de preguntas.

La primera necesito hacer algo parecido a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un botón para iniciar un vídeo.

Este es mi código del vídeo, en la etiqueta src ingreso la ruta del vídeo.

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls id="content_video preload="auto">
<source src=""></source>
</video>
```

Mi segunda pregunta es que si se puede modificar el atributo controls para quitar la opción de descargar el vídeo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo su inquietud, ¿qué error o qué es lo que desea lograr? **[edit] su pregunta con mas detalles**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te dejo el código que preparé en base a lo que necesitas:

```js
$('.custom-play').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#video').get(0).play();
});
```

```css
.custom-play {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url(../images/button-play.png) center center no-repeat
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="freq-content">
  <video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls controlsList="nodownload">
    <source src="http://html5facil.com/demos/videos/big_buck_bunny.webm"  type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
    <source src="http://html5facil.com/demos/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1,mp4a"'>
  </video>
  <br />
  <div class="custom-play"> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

También dejo el link a JSFiddle por si gustas probar el código:

https://jsfiddle.net/eccu8m24/23/

Para el botón de inicio puedes colocar una imagen a tu gusto, una vez que el usuario de click dentro del video se empezará a reproducir.

En cuanto a tu pregunta de "remover el botón descargar" solo necesitas agregar el atributo `controlsList="nodownload"` para que no se muestre:

```
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls controlsList="nodownload">
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvió a la perfección

Comment: Que bueno que haya sido de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: Me ganaste la respuesta. Estaba desarrollando algo más largo, pero que va xD, en fin, una observación: El atributo `controlsList` está disponible desde Chrome 58 en adelante, y de momento solo compatible con Chrome y Opera ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/controlsList), en inglés). Si se quisiera una solución para Firefox/IE/Safari u otros, se tendría que crear una barra de controles personalizada.

Comment: @BDOM Te recomiendo que pegues el código en la propia respuesta (Cntrl+M). Así, en caso de que un día dejara de funcionar jsfiddle, la respuesta seguiría siendo válida.

Comment: @Mariano y Francisco Romero tienen razón, editaré mi respuesta. De igual modo dejaré el link de JsFiddle por si se ofrece, gracias por su comentario a ambos.

Comment: @BDOM claro, cualquier enlace que sirva viene bien (no es un problema de tener un enlace a otra web, al contrario, es poder tener una respuesta completa)... Tené en cuenta que cuando es código JavaScript se puede usar un snippet